# Applying FIFO using Median Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, median, fifo

Good Day Everyone. I have an Excel Formula problem which I could solve partially and want your help to make it robust.

Please see screenshot of the data below
[image]

In the sample data, `Column B` to `Column H` are list of products and their month of purchase. `Column J` is the sale. I want to split `Column J` by FIFO (First In First Out) method (see `Column S` to `Column X`) so that there's no balance left once the split is done. I have placed a check in `Column Z` for the same.

The formula I'm using to achieve this is `=MEDIAN(0,L4-K4,$J4-K4)` in cell `S4`. I have dragged this same formula to the other cells.

The formula works fine for product A to D but as soon as I have a negative value in my purchase, my formula doesn't work (see product E & F in rows highlighted in red). My desired result for product E & F is shown in green highlighted rows.

Thanks.

Comment: No sane person is going to download a stranger's file on the internet.

Comment: @findwindow what should I do? is there a safe or reliable way of doing this?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73337300/edit) to provide a minimal, complete sample as a table in your question

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks. I have added a screenshot of the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Below formula in cell `M4` solved my problem:

```
=(IF(($K4-SUM(($C4:C4)))<0,0,($K4-SUM(($C4:C4)))))-(IF(($K4-SUM(($C4:D4)))<0,0,($K4-SUM(($C4:D4)))))
```

See screenshot below:
[image]